# Improperly Configured -success_url in Django

Tags: django, url

I've got problem with success_url, rather then site I see an ImproperlyConfigured TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'. 
Here is my views.py:

```
class CarRentView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = CarRentForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('cars')
    success_message = "You rent a car"
```

my models.py:

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    rentus = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    rentcar = models.ForeignKey(Car, null=True)
```

and forms.py:

class CarRentForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Rental
    fields = '__all__'
```

and my url:

```
url(r'^car/rent$', CarRentView.as_view(), name = 'rent'),
```

I want to after rent user will see sucess message on carsite.

Comment: Please show the 'cars' view that you are redirecting to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the form is successfully submitted, you are redirecting to the url named `cars`. You haven't shown this view, but the error message is telling you that you haven't set `template_name` for it. You should add something like the following.

```
class CarView(...):
    template_name = 'cars.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to name the template where success page should show up:

```
url(r'^car/rent$', CarRentView.as_view(template_name="success.html"), name = 'rent'),
```